# Using your own web scrapers and data spiders - how to avoid getting blocked?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

One of our PoC's uses web scrapers/spiders to populate segmented data sets.  In making this a platform, the traffic across these spiders will significantly increase.  I have noticed that some hosts will block data requests from specific IP addresses, so using something like [Nutch](https://qbox.io/blog/scraping-the-web-with-nutch-for-elasticsearch) or our own spiders can prove difficult.

We have also seen many data aggregation websites like Indeed (for jobs/resumes).  How can we (and do they) get around being blocked when trying to query RSS data from various sources?